# How to change SVG file direct in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svg

I want to change SVG images direct in Xcode (fill, height, weight), but I can't find this opportunity. I found this message, but I can't understand at third case, where this editor is.

@here because it came up earlier - here’s how we usually add icons / images to our projects (or at least how I like to do it):

1. Find the icon at https://materialdesignicons.com/
2. Get an SVG (click icon > “Icon Package” > “.SVG Optimized”)
3. If, like in the case of CONFERENCE / REPORT, most icons are white, change the color of the SVG to white (by adding fill="#ffffff" to the path, see example below)

4. Remove the empty spaces around the icon (see screenshot “empty_border” below), but ideally make sure the icon is square (I like to use https://www.photopea.com/ for this)
5. [optional: using SVG instead of PDF is fine too] convert the SVG to PDF (again, I use https://www.photopea.com/)
6. Give the asset a descriptive name (and an ic_ prefeix, if it is an icon), like ic_my-new-icon
7. Add the new asset to the asset catalogue, check “Preserve Vector Data” and set its scale to “Single Scale” (see screenshot “image_settings” below)

Comment: When selected, on the bottom left of the mini-inter screen, clic on "Advanced Export", then change the "Foreground" color there. Might be interesting also to tell from where you've found that "tutorial"

Comment: A work colleague sent me this message with that "tutorial" :))